# Why I cant retrive data from mongodb in my simple web application?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am trying to connect mongodb to my express nodejs web application. I am fresh new to nodejs. I am following [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eB9Fq9I5ocs) tutorial video but I couldn't complete it due to the connection of mongodb.

the app.js code I have:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');



Genre = require('./models/genre');

let conn = mongoose.connection;
conn.openUri('mongodb://localhost/bookstore');

conn.on('error', err => console.error('mongodb connection error', 
err));
conn.on('connected', () => console.info(`Connected to mongodb`));
conn.on('disconnected', () => console.info('Disconnected from 
mongodb'));

app.get('/', function(req, res){
res.send('Hello World');
});

app.get('api/genres', function(req , res){
Genre.getGenres(function(err, genres){
    if(err){
        throw err;
    }
    res.json(genres);
})
});

app.listen(3666);
console.log('Server Running On http://localhost:3666');
```

and this is the genre.js

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');


var genreSchema = mongoose.Schema({
name:{
    type: String,
    requires: true
},
create_date:{
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now
 }
});

var Genre = module.exports = mongoose.model('Genre', genreSchema);

module.exports.getGenres = function(callback, limit){
Genre.find(callback).limit(limit);

}
```

and this is a picture of the database in the terminal

```
https://i.stack.imgur.com/S3gFb.png
```

And the information in genres collection in the database

```
https://i.stack.imgur.com/sJFE6.png
```

Once I open the main page I get the Hello World but once I add api/genres which I should get the data from mongodb I get this error

```
https://i.stack.imgur.com/B4c8o.png
```

and this is the files structures

```
https://i.stack.imgur.com/okHIN.png
```

I know this is a basic question but I couldnt figured out I check on google there are others way to connect to the database but I need to know why this particular way which I just followed from the tutorial video havent worked.
As you noticed I am a new to nodejs web development so if you could suggest websites or youtube channels to get me start it I would appreciate it.

Comment: What is the port that mongodb is running? 'mongodb://localhost/bookstore. May be just a port issue / connection issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that it is not a db connection problem. Route matching `http://localhost:3666/api/genres` is not found in your application. Replace `api/genres` with `/api/genres` and I guess everything will work properly